# Did I update Plutus Apps Repo Wrong?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, plutus-starter

I just did a git pull updating my plutus repos from the one used in plutus pioneers 3 to the full state. I did not choose to move the HEAD to the commit mentioned and wanted to see what happens if I build the whole thing (all the other steps are as we told to do them) the interesting this is that the sample code does not compile [image]

Answer (score 0):

After Double Checking, you must specify the tag of the repo when building it via git checkout. It seems that the build from the main folder would not necessarily go to the newest possible version.

Also if you have a repo and are looking to make the right environment checkout lecture 1 of the PPP course and Dr. Larz will show you how to find the right version. Its basically in the cabal file file of the project.

Note: I was going to delete/close this post, but I thought it might become useful to future PPP students when they decide to update their envs to ill be leaving it up. Hope it helps.